# Wordpress - translate widgets (widget areas) using WPML

Tags: wordpress, wpml

How to translate widgets using WPML?

Let's say I have text widget in footer that I want to have in 2 languages. Is there a human way to make it happen with WPML?

Widget Logic doesn't seem to be an answer because it lacks usability. Even I (as a developer) find it hard to use but the translations must be easy enough, that my customer could manage the content all by him/herself.

If I decide to use Widget Logic then my customer will definitely be as pleased with the work as he/she would be with more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways. Widget Logic is one (I don't see how it lacks usability though? I can understand for an end-user, but to a dev it's a very straightforward plugin, isn't it?).

Another way would be to use to use Multilingual Text widget, which is included in WPML's string translation module.

Yet another would be to actually use the string translation, WPML has got a whole section for translating widgets.

Comment: Usability is bad because I have to Google always to find what should be in the logic field (would be better if there is a dropdown list with languages). Problem escalates when I have for example 10 languages, then there will be crazy amounts of widgets in widget areas.

Comment: If you want a dropdown, use Multilingual Text widget. You will still have the problem of many widgets though, no way around that unless you use string translation directly.